# the value in TemplateDriven Form can't change the view in angular

Tags: angular, forms

The code is below. When I choose the value of selectedConfig.isDataRequest, I hope the the template will change based on the value of selectedConfig.isDataRequest, but it seems not worked.

```
<nz-form-item class="dct-col-24">
          <nz-form-label nzSpan="8">数据来源</nz-form-label>
          <nz-form-control nzSpan="16">
            <nz-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedConfig.isDataRequest">
              <label nz-radio [nzValue]=0>默认值</label>
              <label nz-radio [nzValue]=1>固定值</label>
            </nz-radio-group>
          </nz-form-control>
        </nz-form-item>
        <ng-template *ngIf="selectedConfig.isDataRequest==0">
          <nz-form-item class="dct-col-24">
            <nz-form-label nzSpan="8">数据值</nz-form-label>
            <nz-form-control nzSpan="16">
              <nz-select nzAllowClear [(ngModel)]="selectedConfig.defaultValue">
                <nz-option [nzLabel]="'test1'" [nzValue]="1">
                </nz-option>
                <nz-option [nzLabel]="'test2'" [nzValue]="2">
                </nz-option>
              </nz-select>
            </nz-form-control>
          </nz-form-item>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template *ngIf="selectedConfig.isDataRequest==1">
          <nz-form-item class="dct-col-24">
            <nz-form-label nzSpan="8">数据值</nz-form-label>
            <nz-form-control nzSpan="16">
              <input nz-input [(ngModel)]="selectedConfig.defaultValue">
            </nz-form-control>
          </nz-form-item>
        </ng-template>
```

Comment: Does the `selectedConfig.isDataRequest` change from value? If so do you have `changedetection` set to `onpush`?

Comment: Yes,  the `selectedConfig.isDataRequest` changed from value. I have tried to set the  `changedetection`  to `onpush`, then I listen the `(ngModelChange) ="testChange($event)"`, In  the testChange(), I console the value and fired the markForChecke();  but It still not work

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: How can I fix this? [edit on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a78m89),

Comment: I have made some changes to your example hope you can use this: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nq939p)

Comment: Yeah, thank you! It worked. But why the traditional way not worked?

Comment: Oh, no,  I found the reason. It just because the the type of the test is `string`,